# why javascript regexp doesn't match

Tags: javascript, regex

`(new RegExp('/videos/(\d+)$')).test('/videos/1')` returns false. Why?

```
(new RegExp('/videos/(\d+)$')) == /\/videos\/(d+)$/
```

begins with `/`, then goes `videos` string, then `/` again and then `d+` which is 1 or more digits, so `1` should match...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the `\\`:

```js
console.log( (new RegExp('/videos/(\\d+)$')).test('/videos/1') );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should escape special characters in a RegExp constructor:

```js
alert((new RegExp("\\/videos\\/(\\d+)$")).test('/videos/1'))
```

[MDN excerpt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

> When using the constructor function, the normal string escape rules
>   (preceding special characters with \ when included in a string) are
>   necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
var s = '/videos/1';
s.match(/\/videos\/(\d+)$/);
```

As does this:

```
var regex = new RegExp(/\/videos\/(\d+)$/)
regex.test('/videos/1')
```

Are you seeing something different?